# Excel VBA split single excel sheet into multiple workbooks with multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am wanting to split a large excel sheet into multiple workbooks with a varying number of sheets.

Example:

```
BBB 217
BBB 218
BBB 219
BBB 220
BBB 221
BBB 222
BBB 223
BBB 224
BBB 225
BBB 226
CCC 300
CCC 301
CCC 302
CCC 303
CCC 304
CCC 305
CCC 306
DDD 444
DDD 445
DDD 446
DDD 447
```

Where a workbook named BBB would have sheets 217-226, CCC has 300-306, DDD has 444-447. Workbook names start in B2 and corresponding sheets start in C2.

Comment: Post some of your code so we can help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do. Not very neat but all the comments tell you how it works and you can make necessary changes. Change folder path on line "AAA" to your folder path.

```
Sub splitWorkbooksWorksheet()

Dim splitPath As String

Dim w As Workbook 'added workbook objects
Dim ws As Worksheet 'added worksheet objects
Dim wsh As Worksheet 'current active worksheet

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lastr As Long
Dim wbkName As String
Dim wksName As String

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
splitPath = "G:\splitWb\" 'AAA --- PATH TO FOLDER WHERE TO SAVE WORKBOOKS

'last row based on column C worksheet names
lastr = wsh.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

'workbook object
Set w = Workbooks.Add

'this loop through each rows from row 1
'and set new worksheets in workbook w
'check if next rows carries the same
'workbook name if not save and close workbook w
For i = 1 To lastr
  wbkName = wsh.Cells(i, 2)
  w.Worksheets.Add(After:=w.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = wsh.Cells(i, 3)
  If Not wsh.Cells(i + 1, 2) Like wsh.Cells(i, 2) Then
    w.SaveAs splitPath & wsh.Cells(i, 2)
    w.Close
    Set w = Workbooks.Add
  End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Cheers

Pascal

http://multiskillz.tekcities.com

Comment: Just to add, I assumed a change in the workbook name triggers a change of workbook and not worksheet name like 200, 300 ... which would require additional testing conditions